# How do I make many divs fit into one box?

Tags: css

I want to make a box that fits many div,
for example, I have a box, and there are divs aligned horizontally

[image]

and if it doesn't fit, it stacks down horizontally again

[image]

How do I make that kind of thing?

Comment: You can read Css flex

Comment: Read about CSS flexbox and grid

Comment: Please remember that SO is about helping you with code questions, AFTER you've tried to solve the problem yourself. SO is a wiki, not a forum, so asking "how tos" without putting in effort is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Flexbox ([here's](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) a fantastic article to get you started).

You can "wrap" the elements as they reach the end of their parent container. Try changing the size of your screen when running the code below and see how the boxes go to the next line.

```css
.parent{
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  
 /* these two are the important bits */
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child{
border: 1px solid red;
margin: 2px;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: May I suggest you make parent element resizable for a better visual representation?

Comment: @vanowm good point. Done

Comment: I meant with `resize: both; overflow: hidden;` type ;)